# "Logging output too large. Truncating output." Yet, I am NOT using LOGGER?

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on, doc

If I'm not using Logger, what does this message mean AND what are strategies to resolve it. Thx.

GAS, Doc, Add-on.

Comment: It's possible that someone else has had this issue and knows exactly what to tell you, but the chances of that are extremely small.  You need to do the work to isolate what is causing the problem.  When I have a problem like this, I make sure that I have a back up of my script/file and then start omitting / commenting out / deleting code until I don't get the error any more.  It's very time consuming and frustrating, but I don't know of any other way to do it.

Comment: Thx, Sandy.  I was afraid of that response as I've about 5k lines to sift through.

Comment: You can cut the 5k lines down to 2.5k lines by removing half.  Although that may not be possible to get rid of half and still have you Add-on work.  But, the point is, try to remove as large as possible sections first, then you are eliminating large sections in one test.

Comment: Take a look at  your execution log to see if that can help.

Comment: Thx, Cooper.  The Logging error message is from the first line of the Execution Transcript.  I've read through the transcript and I can't quite figure out what the log tells me.  There are several unexpected lines in the transcript before I arrive at one I recognize, which is located at the very beginning of my HTML coding.    I'm going to try the Sandy's approach, keep cutting the code in half. ...fingers crossed.

Comment: I just figured HOW to use the Transcript for this issue: time stamp.
**** Line Space*****
[17-07-05 05:14:48:816 PDT] Logging output too large. Truncating output.
**** Line Space*****
[17-07-05 05:14:48:096 PDT] TableCell.editAsText() [0 seconds]
[17-07-05 05:14:48:096 PDT] Text.getText() [0 seconds]

The Truncation occurred at the 48:816 mark.  I had assumed the lines were listed in chronological order.  The Truncting one, the first, wasn't listed in order.   I'll go there and begin.  Cooper, thanks, your comment opened my perspective.